# Save Form Fields After Failed Validation With ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a C# form which uses a ViewModel. The Get function calls the view like this:

```
return View(viewmodel);
```

In my Post function, I'm validating the form fields and then using this to return to the view:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ViewData["wo_id"] = wo_id;
    var viewmodel = new AEO.WorkOrder.Domain.ViewModels.WorkOrderDetailsViewModel(wo_id);
    viewmodel.GetWOIMDetails();
    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

The problem is if the form fails validation, the refreshed page comes back with all of the fields blank. How can I save the information in these fields on the refresh?

**Edit: Here is the view**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AEO.WorkOrder.Domain.ViewModels.WorkOrderDetailsViewModel>" %>

<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
<% Html.BeginForm("InternationalTransportationAddDetails","InternationalMove", FormMethod.Post); %>
<input id="comments" type="text" name="comments"/><%= Html.ValidationMessage("Comments", "*") %>
<input type="submit" value="Submit New Details" id="submit" name="submit" />   <br />
<input type="hidden" value="<%= ViewData["wo_id"] %>" id="wo_id" name="wo_id" />   <br />
```

Comment: Have you tried to comment the two lines above `return View(viewmodel);` in your post controller action method?

Comment: Add your code in the view file

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post-action, you are returning a NEW instance of the viewmodel, and NOT the post-model.  example of what it should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InternationalTransportationAddDetails(WorkOrderDetailsViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ViewData["wo_id"] = wo_id;  // however you get wo_id

    return View(model);
  }

  // if valid, process model here
}
```

See how I have returned the posted model?  Now if your form's values don't match your viewmodel, then you'll have to create a new instance of your viewmodel, but also include the post-model's values as part of the viewmodel:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InternationalTransportationAddDetails(SomeModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ViewData["wo_id"] = wo_id;
    var viewmodel = new AEO.WorkOrder.Domain.ViewModels.WorkOrderDetailsViewModel(wo_id);
    viewmodel.comments = model.Comments;
    return View(viewmodel);
  }
```

So in this example, we've taken our form's model, and if the validation fails, we apply the property from that model back to our view model, and then return the view model.
      // if valid, process model here
    }

Comment: I think this is correct, and it falls under the second example.The comments field  isn't actually in the view model since I was just handling it manually. Is there any way to get around moving all of the data into the view model?

Comment: You might want to create a custom post-model that's specifically for your form's fields, and then make that model a property of your ViewModel.  When you submit your form, you can just accept your custom model in the post-action, but if validation fails and you need to return the viewmodel, you can assign the custom model to your ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate your form inputs so that they correctly re-display the attempted values.

```
Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.Comments)
```

or

```
Html.TextBox("Comments")
```